# Delete an Answer if Duplicate Found After Posting?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just answered a [quick question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914746/datepicker-shows-calendar-on-pageload/24914801#24914801) that popped up on my feed, but after answering the question I discovered that it is nearly an [exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580727/override-jquery-ui-datepicker-div-visible-strangely-on-first-page-load) of a previously-asked question.

**Should I delete my answer?** I've edited my answer to link to the duplicate question and I've flagged the question; however I feel that since the duplicate is relatively well-answered, my answer is not contributing anything *new*.

Comment: See [Should I delete my answer to a question that's marked as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132600/should-i-delete-my-answer-to-a-question-thats-marked-as-a-duplicate) As an aside, it seems like the OP isn't loading any CSS for jQuery UI. If they don't create their own theme or use one of the defaults, any widgets they use will look crappy. None of the answers to either question mention this...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Thanks for the link! Can't believe I didn't find that beforehand. The question wasn't about the "crappy" styling -- it was about the DatePicker displaying itself on page-load. I'd view extra information like that as "question clutter," but I see your point. If it was something *vital*, then it'd definitely be worth mentioning.

Comment: The datepicker doesn't display on page load if you use one of the default jQuery UI themes.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you're trying to say. I'll add that to the answer in that case (although it is closed now). Fair point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be tempted delete the answer - depending on whether I thought I'd added anything extra to the solution or not. In that case it might be better to add your answer to the original question instead.

I would definitely flag/vote to close as a duplicate.

(BTW I've closed the question as a duplicate )

Comment: If you added something extra, shouldn't you look into contributing that "extra" to the duplicate target instead?

Comment: @Deduplicator - Good point.

Comment: And if you delete your answer despite it being upvoted, the Internet unicorns smile on you. But it highlights a serious **fail** of the gamification that is meant to encourage people to do *the right thing*.